# ngx-cookieconsent initialize$ not working

Tags: initialization, cookieconsent

I am using ngx-cookieconsent and it is working as expected except for the initialize$ callback function.

```
this.initializeSubscription = this.cookieConsentService.initialize$.subscribe(
      (event: NgcInitializeEvent) => {
        console.log('cookie config ',this.cookieConsentService.getConfig());
      });
```

Although the cookie consent popup is displayed, it seems that  initialize is never called. There are no errors but the log never prints to the console while other logging is printed.

Here is my config (although I don't think it is related)

```
const cookieConfig:NgcCookieConsentConfig = {
  enabled: true,
  cookie: {
    domain: environment.domain
  },
  "palette": {
    "popup": {
      "background": "#237afc"
    },
    "button": {
      "background": "#fff",
      "text": "#237afc"
    }
  },
  theme: 'block',
  type: 'info'
};
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: I think this is still not fixed and might be related to a [bug in the core library](https://github.com/osano/cookieconsent/issues/474). This is fixed now, but not yet published. If you found a good workaround I would be interested.